# Why are my references to subplots wrongly ordered

Tags: subfloats, overleaf, ref

I am following [this overleaf template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/technion-iit-thesis-template/rzqpztzgppwz), which is a release of this [github repository](https://github.com/eyalroz/technion-iit-thesis).

I am opening the template, as is, without changing compilers or anything else, as I am not an expert on the subject and I do not want to mess anything up. I have added the following lines to `my-general.tex`, lines 16,17:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
```

And the following lines to `mainchap1.tex`, lines 119-132:

```
Figure~\ref{figa}

\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth, height=5cm]{graphics/mygraphic1.pdf}
            \caption{}\label{figa}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth, height=5cm]{graphics/mygraphic1.pdf}
            \caption{}\label{figb}
    \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Two circles and a wavy line.}
\end{figure}
```

The result is that the reference to the subfigure is all messed up:

[image]

This should be `Figure 3.2a`. What happened here and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm on support staff at Overleaf.)

This is a bit of an odd one. The template was last published to Overleaf with the TeX Live 2016 image selected, so any new projects created from the template will use TeX Live 2016.

But in TeX Live 2016, the situation around the handling of bidirectional text was different. This is what causes the problems with the numbering order for the subfigure reference. The template author says as much in several GitHub issues where moving to a newer TeX Live version solves similar problems with captions/numbering and cross-referencing.

However, the template in Overleaf is an old release (it doesn't exactly match the current files on GitHub). So you will run into other errors if you change the TeX Live version to a newer one on Overleaf. [Using the Overleaf project menu – TeX Live version](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Using_the_Overleaf_project_menu#TeX_Live_version).

Commenting out lines 11-21 of misc/my-thesis-specific.tex is enough to get you up and running on Overleaf's TeX Live 2018 image with correct subfigure references. Generally modifying distributed files is not recommended, but this is the quickest fix if you need to get up and running quickly.

If you want to move to TeX Live 2020 as recommended by the template author ([ref.](https://github.com/eyalroz/technion-iit-thesis/issues/36)), you would need to incorporate more of the recent changes in GitHub, which have not yet been published in the Overleaf template. But the best long-term solution is to ask the template author to update the template in Overleaf, so that these manual adjustments are not necessary. This can be done by the original template author following these steps: [How do I update a template, example or article I've published in the Overleaf gallery?](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/How_do_I_update_a_template,_example_or_article_I%27ve_published_in_the_Overleaf_gallery%3F)